# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables- React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have been trying to build my react native project but getting error

React native version : .48.4

Xcode : 9.1

```
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2017.1/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Hi, Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 72):

You need to run the below command to squash the error

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Note: Depending on your Xcode version installed, sometimes you have to add it to the path, for example `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.0.app/Contents/Developer/`

Comment: I changed my application name from Xcode 9 to Xcode and ran this command. This worked for me. Thanks :-)

Comment: @JageetMohanJ  This worked for me. Renamed 'Xcode 2' to 'Xcode'. WORKED!! strange!

Comment: we need to point to the latest xcode if there are more than 1 xcode installed on system

Comment: Awesome, fixed my problem! 
Thanks

Comment: works like a charm! accept that as right response!

Comment: I suggest to remove spaces from app name as it may cause another issues:
``Xcode 12.0.app`` -> ``Xcode_12.0.app`` 
So the command look like that:
``sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12.0.app/Contents/Developer/`` without any spaces is the path.

Comment: Path updated, thank you

Answer (score 32):

This solved that issue for me

```
rm -r ~/.rncache/
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
./configure --host arm-apple-darwin
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue,

below steps worked for me,

- Restart your system
- under repo: cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4
- ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh

Comment: One of those few instances where restarting actually was the difference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

From this comment: [configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables- React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928498/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-react-native#comment85298270_49032986)

Changing the name of the app from `~/Downloads/Xcode 10.1.app` to `~/Downloads/Xcode.app` fixed this problem for me. I wonder if it has to do with the space in the app name?

Comment: sudo xcode-select -s ~/Downloads/Xcode 10.1.app/Contents/Developer/

Comment: sudo xcode-select -s ~/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

Comment: I can confirm it still does not like spaces in the XCode App. I changed "Xcode 11.3" to "Xcode11.3" and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason is that dependency could not find Xcode command tools.

So Just check :

xcode-select -s

- Shows any Xcode tools
- If not, Install Xcode Command Tools
- If Xcode tools already install set the path
- xcode-select -p *Path to Xcode* Eg: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode 11.5.app/Contents/Developer/
- In my case the issue is space in the path 'Xcode 11.5' rename and remove space 'Xcode11.5' then **it works fine**.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes some scripts can not read past spaces. For example for a path -

`Desktop/Folder/A B/Xcode.app`

the script will read it like this -

`Desktop/Folder/A`

So make sure your XCode directory name contains no space in any of the folder names in between. Then point your command line tool to your prefered XCode by running this command on terminal -

```
sudo xcode-select -s "PATH TO YOUR XCODE"/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue. To resolve this, You have to follow the below steps:

1. Check the Xcode application name. If it has space (i.e. Xcode 11.1) then remove it (Xcode11.1).
2. Open Terminal and type below command:

   > `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode11.1.app/Contents/Developer/`
3. Then run `Pod install`

I hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed `/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app` to `/Applications/Xcode.app` and the pod install went through.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
In my case issue with xcode path it contain space so remove that space

```
From:- /Volumes/MACMINI DATA SSD/XCode/Xcode_12.4.app
To:- /Volumes/MACMINI_DATA_SSD/XCode/Xcode_12.4.app
```

then run following command and restart

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Volumes/MACMINI_DATA_SSD/XCode/Xcode_12.4.app
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had to spend a lot more time to find the exact issue. Finally, the issue was, it had space in between the XCode path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting my computer fixed this for me. Probably won't help everyone who is seeing this error, but in my case it was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed the new Xcode, the application remained in my `Downloads` directory. This was the issue.

Solution:

> Move the Xcode application from `Downloads` into the `Applications` directory